# Adding a tag is a minor edit?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

I [edited](https://askubuntu.com/suggested-edits/5656) (or rather, suggested an edit) on a question about Chuck montages on Planet Ubuntu, to add the tag 'planet-ubuntu'. It was rejected with the following reason:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

If the reason said that we don't need a planet-ubuntu tag or something like that, it would have been fine. But why is adding a tag too minor an edit? Is adding a tag always a too-minor edit, or are there situations in which adding a tag is acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

It often makes sense to add one tag. But we require that you have [500 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/retag-questions) before you can re-tag questions. You also need [300 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/create-tags) to create a new tag.

- Suggested edits should always be substantial improvements to the post.
  You're encouraged to improve the wording, grammar, spelling and layout of the post as well.

In this particular case, I think the planet-ubuntu tag is indeed unnecessary. The community tag covers all questions related to the planet, and the fewer tags we have, the better.